# nodejs set environment variables in production server

Tags: node.js, production-environment, production

I have around 20+ environment variables, some of them are very sensitive information, like db connections, passwords, secrets, aws keys, etc...
and that can't be anywhere in the source code.

I'm using dotenv in development, but what about production? do I have to set each variable before running node? is there any better way to do that?

**Update**
I'm using azure VM at the moment, but I'm moving towards aws

Comment: where is your server? heroku, aws?

Comment: I have azure VM at the moment, but I'll use aws later.

Comment: than you can use dotenv on production as well

Comment: it's not recommended that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding AWS It depends on your deployment.

Both beanstalk and lambda support environmental variables.
In case of an EC2 deployment you can add some sensitive information encrypted with user data, or specify a mechanism to setup the environmental variables from a safe place.

For example you can create and ec2 machine with a role which has access to s3 where your environmental variables reside.
Your user data script might utilize this role and setup the environmental variables from s3.

When it comes to encryption you can also check [Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/).